# Use baked texture on the same object creates lines without color

Tags: uv, texture-baking

To understand UV Mapping more I created a UV Sphere and a material which is totally black.
I also created a yellow material and assigend it to some faces.
Then I baked three textures (high 2048x2048, mid 1024x1024, low 512x512) and saved the uv sphere as a wavefront obj file. I also set the margin to 0 because I don't want to waste space.

[image: Top of UV Sphere]
[image: Low texture]

Then I opened blender new, imported the obj file (with the uv coordinates of course) and added a new material. I added a texture to that material and choose as Type Image or Movie. I choose the low image and the right UV Map. I thought it's working like it should but when I let Blender render that image I have ugly white lines between the "parts" where the smart uv map "cut" through the mesh.

[image]

When I change the method how the viewport is displayed as textured - then there are no lines.

What is the problem? Do I need to set margin to 1?

Comment: This is known as texture bleeding, the UVs do not have a large enough margin, so the surrounding colors leak through.

Comment: You should listen to yourself , Before asking if you should change the margin to 1 , You should try it. Of course , If that doesnt work you will need to change the margin to around 5